# Java - printing textual representation of objects in sets

Tags: java

I have a `Map` with keys as `String` and values as a set of objects.

How would I go about printing out the object associated with each individual key and its attributes?

I have something like this so far:

```
for (String eachKey : aMap.keySet()) {
    System.out.println(eachKey + " :" + aMap.get(eachKey));
}
```

This just prints out the key with the object identity.

Comment: Either you redefine `toString()` for this class (your IDE can propose a default one) or you define a `print()` method that you call in the loop or you use reflexion in order to list every attribute/value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to override the `toString` method from your class.

E.g.:

**MyClass**

```
class MyClass {

    int i = 1;
    String s = "test";

    MyClass(int i, String s) {
        this.i = i;
        this.s = s;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MyObject [i=" + i + ", s=" + s + "]";
    }

}
```

and the class containing the `main` method:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class A {

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Set<MyClass>> aMap = new HashMap<>();
        aMap.put("firstKey", new HashSet<MyClass>() {
            {
                add(new MyClass(1, "a"));
                add(new MyClass(2, "b"));
            }
        });
        aMap.put("secondKey", new HashSet<MyClass>() {
            {
                add(new MyClass(3, "c"));
            }
        });
        for (String eachKey : aMap.keySet()) {
            System.out.println(eachKey + " :" + aMap.get(eachKey));
        }
    }

}
```

The output will be:

```
firstKey :[MyObject [i=2, s=b], MyObject [i=1, s=a]]
secondKey :[MyObject [i=3, s=c]]
```

Notice that usually your IDE has the ability to generate the `toString` method for you:

- **Eclipse**: Source > Generate toString()...
- **IntelliJ IDEA**: Code > Generate... > toString()

Comment: Very clear and concise explanation :) managed to get this working now.

Answer (score 1):

Override the `toString()` method in Object class. `System.out.println()` will call toString() of the object, the Object class will only print classname@ if you have not defined toString() method in your class.